# Using a value of a struct from workspace in a script based on its name

Tags: matlab, struct, simulink

I'm working on a project and I need to work with certain variables from the workspace and I only have their name as a char array.

To make an example, I have array

```
var_names = {'var1', 'var2', ... }
```

and these variables are (among many others) in the workspace as structs with multiple attributes - value, class etc. (I believe these are Simulink generated but I am not absolutely certain).

To simplify, say I have the names {'var1', 'var2'} and I need to make a product of their values

```
prod = var1.Value * var2.Value
```

I tried things like

```
var_names(1).Value * var_names(2).Value
```

and similar more obvious attempts but none were successful. A note - the eval doesn't work because of the struct nature of the variables and I need something else.

Comment: Show how you used eval please.

Comment: If you can sort all variables in a master structure, you can access the variables like this: `masterStruct.(var_names{1})`. This is much faster than `eval`.

Comment: @Anthony Faster and *safer*

Comment: I used eval similarly as in your answer, Mad Physicist. I can't remember the exact use but the problem is it doesn't work with Simulink.Parameter. The strange thing is that the code I wrote works in another script I wrote to test it but when I copy the exact same code into the large function I'm working on fixing, it stops working, saying Error using eval, Undefined function or variable 'Nameofvar'. Also, for some reason, if I change the value of said variable manually, it works for the one var and then breaks at the next one.

Comment: If you could show a sample of the misbehaving code, we'd be able to help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51476571/matlab-getting-value-of-simulink-struct-from-workspace-by-its-name

I've created a new post for that since this one is asking something more general. The new question hopefully provides enough information about my issue in a more organized manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to get a variable by name is using [`eval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html). The important thing is to make sure to evaluate the right text:

```
names = {'var1', 'var2'};
x1 = eval(names{1});
x2 = eval(names{2});
prod = x1.Value * x2.Value
```