# How do I get the value of a Simulink struct from the workspace within a MATLAB function?

Tags: matlab, global-variables, simulink, data-dictionary

I need to access the values of variables in MATLAB's workspace of type `Simulink.parameter`:

```
CAL_vars = dsdd('find','/path/CAL','ObjectKind','Variable','Property',{'name' 'Class' 'value' 'CAL'}) 
%gets ids of variables in data dictionary
i = 10
for i=1:length(CAL_vars)
       var_name = dsdd('GetAttribute',CAL_vars(i),'name');
       % gets names of variables in data dict
       var_eval = eval(var_name); % this works in standalone script and it does exactly 
       % what I need, but once i put it in the function I need this for, it returns error
       if (length(var_eval.Value) ==1)
           if (var_eval.Value == true)
               var_eval.Value = 1;
           elseif (var_eval.Value == false)
               var_eval.Value = 0;
           else
           end
       end
       % do something with the Value
       if (errorCode ~= 0)
          fprintf('\nSomething is wrong at %s\n', var_name)
       end
end
```

The problem arises because the structs are of made by Simulink and give error, when I try to call eval(name_of_var): Undefined function 'eval' for input arguments of type 'Simulink.Parameter'.

Curiously, it seems to function properly in a stand-alone script but once I plug it into the larger function, it stops working and starts displaying error saying

```
Error using eval
Undefined function or variable 'name_of_var'.
```

The function is clearly in the workspace.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: you want to access structs from Simulink in the Matlab Workspace?

Comment: I don't know if my terminology is correct - I'm fairly new to Matlab besides some minor projects at the university. There are some variables in the Matlab Workspace  which (I think) were generated by Simulink - now on further inspection, it seems that these are Simulink.Parameter type objects. I'll edit the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Post your dsdd()

Comment: It's part of a larger project so I can't post any details online but I've tested everything regarding it and it's returning correct variable names as expected. I am fairly certain that the heart of the problem lies in the usage of eval on Simulink parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Curiously, it seems to function properly in a stand-alone script but
>   once I plug it into the larger function, it stops working

This is the expected behaviour. A function [has its own workspace](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html) and can't directly access variables in the base workspace.

You could try using [`evalin`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html) instead of `eval`, and specify the `base` workspace:

> `evalin(ws, expression)` executes `expression`, a character vector or
>   string scalar containing any valid MATLAB® expression using variables
>   in the workspace `ws`. `ws` can have a value of `'base'` or `'caller'` to
>   denote the MATLAB base workspace or the workspace of the caller
>   function.

In general though, there are lots of reasons for trying to avoid using `eval` if at all possible (see the MATLAB help for `eval`) and it would be best if you could find a different way of getting this data.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm fairly new to Matlab and didn't realise the separate workspace existed. I figured it out today as well. Sadly, in this case, eval was the only viable option as I was working with code from larger project and didn't have much say in generation of said data.